# Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially

Tags: flutter, get, android-gradle-plugin

Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

Command: C:\Users\AQ\Downloads\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\Users\AQ\Downloads\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root C:\Users\AQ\Downloads\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Dflutter.inspector.structuredErrors=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages "D:\android studio projs\finalProject.dart_tool\package_config.json" --output-dill "D:\android studio projs\finalProject.dart_tool\flutter_build\87203efc84c36e6459ed7b68cb13c50e\app.dill" --depfile "D:\android studio projs\finalProject.dart_tool\flutter_build\87203efc84c36e6459ed7b68cb13c50e\kernel_snapshot.d" --incremental --initialize-from-dill "D:\android studio projs\finalProject.dart_tool\flutter_build\87203efc84c36e6459ed7b68cb13c50e\app.dill" --source file:///D:/android%20studio%20projs/finalProject/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/android%20studio%20projs/finalProject/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --verbosity=error package:project_four/main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\AQ\Downloads\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\AQ\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 5s

i was working in flutter app with firebase and google maps .. i imported the project from git hub
i was tring to add vpn because some packages is prevented from my country
then i found this error

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and I was using FVM in my project, I deleted and reinstall the flutter, it worked for me. Also I accidently add FVM configuration file in git.ignore,I removed that file and run application, it worked completely fine.